# Does HTTPS in my app considered "Encryption"

Tags: iphone, https, app-store

I'm using NSURLRequest in my current app which is in the App Store. I need to change to Https in the next version.

Do I need to declare "Encryption" in the Apple "upload binary" section when submitting the application?

I saw 2 related threads, but I'm not convinced with the answers there. If someone with real experience or knowledge could answer this one, it could be great..

Thanks.

Comment: Could this perhaps be a legal question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only concerns encryption within the application. If you're not doing any of that then you're OK.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

No, they only want to know if you are implementing an encryption algorithm inside the app itself because there are various laws involved in what can be exported to where with regard to types of encryption.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend asking Apple, but I suspect the answer is no.

Refer to Apple's [Export Compliance FAQ](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/4.0.0.9.1.7.1.3.6.1) (needs developer access).