# Does google map api v3 contain encryption

Tags: iphone, encryption, google-maps-api-3, app-store, itunes

)

I have made an app, 
i made a free app, which shows a list with restaurants. To see which restaurants are in your near i implemented the google map api v3. 
On the map are icons which show the restaurants.
When i submitted the app on iTunes, i got the question: Does your product contain encryption?
I have looking for information on the google site about encryption, but i haven't found any information.
I don't know if they use encryption and i don't know which encryption they use.

i read on this [site](http://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/identifying-encryption-items#Three), but i don't know if my app/the google map api v3 is is described by note 4 and free from encryption control.

Has someone experience or information?
Do i need a ERN-Certificate or something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's more to do with whether your application performs any actual encryption in the source code.

See this post - [Does HTTPS in my app considered "Encryption"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324066/does-https-in-my-app-considered-encryption)